# There exists a square matrix $A$ with rational entries and dimension $2019 \times 2019$ such that $A^3 + 6A^2 - 2I = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

**a)** There exists a square matrix $A$ with rational entries and dimension $2019 \times 2019$ such that $A^3 + 6A^2 - 2I = 0$?

**b)** And a square matrix $A$ with rational entries and dimension $2019 \times 2019$ such that $A^4 + 6A^3 - 2I = 0$?

-

Im trying to answer this questions. For the first one, i thought the following:

$A^2\cdot\dfrac{(A + 6I)}{2} = I \Longrightarrow det(A)^2 = \dfrac{2^{2019}}{det(A+6I)}$

Then, because the matrix has rational entries, the determinant of $A$ must be rational, and then:

$det(A + 6I) = k^2\cdot(2^{2n + 1})$, where $k \in \mathbb{Q^*}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

And we obtain $det(A) = \dfrac{2^{1009-n}}{k}$.

I was hopping i could get a contradiction out of this but i'm not able to find one. Any hints? Thanks! (On the question **b)** i tried the same thing but didn't work).

Comment: for part a) how about 673 blocks of A along the main diagonal?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what you said. Can you ellaborate i little bit more? Thanks! (Not a native english speaker here, hahah)

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS WRONG, PLEASE CHECK EDIT**

(a) Let,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then a matrix that'll work is,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & I_{2016} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(b) Let,
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then a matrix that'll work is,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & I_{2015} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The $A$ and $B$ are called [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the corresponding polynomials.

**EDIT :** As pointed out in the comments, the above solution is wrong. I sort of typed it in a hurry, and didn't check if it actually worked or not. I apologise for that. I'm keeping this for context of the comments.

Having said that, as pointed out by @greg in the comments, $I \otimes A$ does work for (a) and (b) is impossible, as pointed out by @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: The idea is good, the execution not so. A, B don't satisfy the equations.

Comment: @TomTom314 you mean A and B satisfy the equations but the matrix that will work does not work

Comment: @Lozenges Yes, that's what I meant. I'm quite sure, that there is no matrix for b) - using jordan normal form.

Comment: In order to satisfy the polynomial, you need to create a block diagonal using the Kronecker product, i.e. 
$$M = I_{673}\otimes A$$
This won't work for the other case unless/until you can find a $3\times 3$ matrix for $B$ which satisfies the second polynomial.

Comment: Agreed: this doesn't work. By introducing the identity as part of the block diagonal form, you are introducing the eigenvalue $1$, which makes $\lambda - 1$ a factor of the minimal polynomial. But $\lambda - 1$ divides neither polynomial.

Comment: What the others said. You get a matrix satisfying the cubic by using 673 diagonal blocks of $A$ (and/or its conjugates). The quartic is impossible. The polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein. Therefore it is the minimal polynomial and hence the matrix is diagonalizable. Consequently its size has to be a multiple of four.